# How to receive the current user with create react app -auth template on net core 3 and identity server

Tags: authorization, identityserver4, create-react-app

I have never used identity server before and I was wondering how to receive the current user info if they have been authenticated using net core 3.

Using the barebones create react app -auth weather app template

in the `WeatherForecastController` we have the authorize attribute:

```
[Authorize]
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
```

With the following endpoint:

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
```

Which will return the correct data if you have logged in and been granted a jwt bearer token.

I would like to create an endpoint that: 
1. Allows anonymous access(logged in or not so the authorize attribute needs ditching or overriding)
2. It should then try to authenticate the user 
3.If the user can be identified then the endpoint will return the correct data else if the user cannot be identified it will return a subset of the data

I'm struggling to retrieve the user who has made the request information, I believe i'm supposed to use `GET /connect/userinfo` identityserver endpoint with the bearer token as a parameter but I have no idea how to do this. I would like to access the user_id so I can corrispond with the identityUser table.

I have also tried:

```
var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity;
IEnumerable<Claim> claims = identity.Claims;
```

It just feels like theres a proper way to do this stuff that i'm missing. I'd be grateful for someone to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 2. It should then try to authenticate the user

Browsers communicate with web applications. You should have a web application to be able to redirect back to IDS4 to login. What you are have is an API. Later Web applications communicate with web APIs. Read more [here](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro/big_picture.html)

> 3. If the user can be identified then the endpoint will return the correct data else if the user cannot be identified it will return a subset of the data

What you are looking for is Authorization, you can manually do this check on the endpoint. You can access current user using `ControllerBase.User` ass a result of passing a valid `JWT` tokens to the API. Considering you already setup authentication using code like bellow:

```
services.AddAuthentication("Bearer").AddJwtBearer("Bearer",
                options =>
                {
                    options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000";
                    options.Audience = "api1";
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                    {
                        NameClaimType = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier"//To set Identity.Name 
                    };
                });
```

> I'm struggling to retrieve the user who has made the request information

You can simply use `ControllerBase.User` to get the current authenticated user on API, no need to call any endpoint.

**Update:** Setting `NameClaimType` as posted on code above will set `Identity.Name` to the user's identifier.

Comment: So the ControllerBase.User holds a list of claims that the authorized user has based on the jwt bearer token the api receives, brilliant.What I don't understand is: If I have an `applicationUser` table, how can I identify from `ControllerBase.User` which user has accessed the endpoint? Thanks for you answer btw

Comment: For example I found out I can use `Request.Headers[HeaderNames.Authorization]` and call the `GET /connect/userinfo` and it will return the users information... But it seems like you can pass the userid maybe in the bearer token somehow? thanks

Comment: Claims contains `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier` which reflects user's ID unless you set it differently on IDS4. you also can set `Identity.Name` to be user's ID by adding this code on API's startup when `AddJwtBearer` - ```options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                    {
                        NameClaimType = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier"
                    };```